# Django allow return response before another proccess finished

Tags: django, gitlab, webhooks

I have a problem when I want to run a webhook. In this case I want to run another script to build the project, let say `runaway.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/myuser/envs/project-vue
git pull https://username:password@gitlab.com/username/project-vue
npm install
npm run build
```

and then in my `views.py`, I try to call it command:

```
@csrf_exempt
def gitlab_webhook_view(request):
    header_signature = request.META.get('HTTP_X_GITLAB_TOKEN')

    if header_signature == settings.GITLAB_WEBHOOK_KEY:
        subprocess.call(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'runaway.sh'))
        return HttpResponse('pull & build welldone!')

    return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission denied.')
```

But gitlab always return `Hook execution failed: Net::ReadTimeout`, As we know `npm install` & `npm run build` take a long time.

So, I want to continuing that process in the background service, and for a few seconds just return `"pull & build welldone!"`. Thank before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) for this:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def pull_proc():
    subprocess.call(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'runaway.sh'))
```

In view you can call this task in background like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def gitlab_webhook_view(request):
    header_signature = request.META.get('HTTP_X_GITLAB_TOKEN')

    if header_signature == settings.GITLAB_WEBHOOK_KEY:
        pull_proc.delay()
        return HttpResponse('pull & build welldone!')

    return HttpResponseForbidden('Permission denied.')
```

You can find description how to setting celery with django [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).